# UITextField Text not refreshing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm having a weird Behaviour by textfield inside TableViewCell. When I set its text at start, it shows well but when I start editing it, the old text is not cleared and written over it. See Images attached. My code is:

```
_meterTF = [[UITextField alloc] init];
_meterTF.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_meterTF.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
_meterTF.font = WO_DETAIL_NORMAL_FONT;
_meterTF.tag = 1;
_meterTF.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
_meterTF.layer.borderColor = GRAY_BORDER_COLOR.CGColor;
_meterTF.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
[_meterTF setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[_meterTF setRightView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5,0, 10, 10)]];
_meterTF.delegate = self;
[_meterTF setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
if (!self.isEditable) {
    _meterTF.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    _meterTF.enabled = NO;
    
}
```

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Here is CellForRow Method. [cell.meterView initSubview] this line actually adds that textField

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *meterCellIdentifier = @"meterCell";
    
    DISMeterTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:meterCellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[DISMeterTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:meterCellIdentifier];
        [cell.historyButon addTarget:self action:@selector(showMeterPreviousHistory:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        cell.meterView.isEditable = (self.isEditMode && self.currentWorkOrderSegment.isEditable) || self.isTechReview;
        [cell.meterView initSubview];

    }
    cell.meterView.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.meterView.section = indexPath.section;
    cell.historyButon.row = indexPath.row;
    cell.historyButon.section = indexPath.section;
    cell.historyButon.enabled = self.currentWorkOrderSegment.isEditable;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewScrollPositionNone;
    [cell.meterView resetView];
    if (self.isEditMode) {
        [cell.meterView renderMeter:self.currentWorkOrderSegment.orderEquipmentMeterListViewModels[self.equipmentIndex].orderEquipmentMeters[indexPath.row] withIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    else
    {
        if(indexPath.section < self.currentWorkOrderSegment.orderEquipmentMeterListViewModels.count && indexPath.row < self.currentWorkOrderSegment.orderEquipmentMeterListViewModels[indexPath.section].orderEquipmentMeters.count)
            [cell.meterView renderMeter:self.currentWorkOrderSegment.orderEquipmentMeterListViewModels[indexPath.section].orderEquipmentMeters[indexPath.row] withIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.meterView.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are adding *another* text field. Where are you executing the code you posted, and where/when are you adding `_meterTF` to the view?

Comment: it looks like textfield created several times. You should create a textfield once, and When dequeue a cell in the cellForRowAt:IndexPath method, you need to set only the value of textfield, instead of creating new textfield..

Comment: Cells are reused. You are missing that concept...

Comment: Updated question

Comment: How do you add `_meterTF` to `cell`?

Comment: @RomanPodymov cell.meterView initSubview, written in question

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use dequeueReusableCell

guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.CellIdentifier.tableViewCell.MyProfileTopTableViewCell, for: indexPath) as? MyProfileTopTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

and add Textfield didchange delegate in cell, so whenever user update textfield data you need to either maintain array/ dictionary and update textfieldata accordionly and in tableview cellforrow just show updated textfield data in cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.CellIdentifier.tableViewCell.MyProfileTopTableViewCell, for: indexPath) as? MyProfileTopTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
let objects = self.textfieldData[indexpath.row]
cell.textfield?.text =  objects
cell.delegate = self
}

class Yourcontroller: textfieldChange
 {
func updateTextfield(text: UITextfield)
{
  self.textfieldData[text.tag] =  text.text
}
}

protocol textfieldChange: class
{
func updateTextfield(text: UITextfield)
}

class MyProfileTopTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   @IBOutlet weak var txtfield: UITextfield?
func updateTextifledcell(data: String, indexPath)
{
self. txtfield =  data
self. txtfield.tag = indexPath.tag
}
var delgate: textfieldChange?
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self. txtfield.delegate = self
self.textField?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(txtEditing), for: .editingChanged)
    }
}
@objc func txtEditing(_ txt : UITextField){
self. delgate. updateTextfield(textView)
}
```

I hope you got my point and it will resolve this issue